# Powershell - Creating Multidimensional Array from CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, multidimensional-array

```
$deviceImport = Import-Csv ".\ValidatedData.csv"

for($i=0; $i -lt $deviceImport.Length; $i++){
    $Devices[$i][0] += $_.id;
    $Devices[$i][1] += $_.name;
}
```

Below is a sample of the CSV File that is presently being passed in is

Id,Type,Name,SpaceId,SpaceName,NetworkSwitchName,NetworkSwitchPortID,ExternalID,SerialNumber
126,NetworkNode,10E-601,,,,,00000100-0001-3A15-0370-B23C28A0569F,
816,NetworkNode,10E-602,,,,,00000100-0001-0000-0000-5012003A0038,
1072,NetworkNode,10E-603,,,,,00000100-0001-0000-0000-500E002E004E,
358,NetworkNode,10E-604,,,,,00000100-0001-03AC-179B-DCC22680568E,
538,NetworkNode,10E-605,,,,,00000100-0001-F74E-08A7-5864E16056AA,
1782,NetworkNode,10E-606,,,,,00000100-0001-1B0C-427A-985C47405665,
399,NetworkNode,10E-607,,,,,00000100-0001-FB3F-B1F0-F95824B0E06A,
305,NetworkNode,10E-608,,,,,00000100-0001-F7FF-825A-C6497C40567F,
227,NetworkNode,10E-609,,,,,00000100-0001-3218-AECE-7BE4DDE05697,
422,NetworkNode,10E-610,,,,,00000100-0001-526F-E1B1-56E1DB90E068,
4087,NetworkNode,10E-611,,,,,00000100-0001-F9CE-5438-19D5FCA0E80B,
250,NetworkNode,10E-612,,,,,00000100-0001-647B-2794-0FB79920568A,
191,NetworkNode,10E-613,,,,,00000100-0001-277E-7457-93DBE6105689,
808,NetworkNode,10E-614,,,,,00000100-0001-0000-0000-510400520029,

I am having Troubles passing this into a jagged array I am attempting to pass each row in as a separate array that I can create an object with and execute commands against this is just a small segment this scales up to 20,000 lines.

Comment: I think you missed the question?

Comment: Please, format your question and add more clearance of what you would like to see as an outcome. Currently `$Devices[$i]` contains an item for each `$deviceImport` (same length) where will the multiple `id`'s and `name`s come from? In other words: how should it be *multidimensional*?

Comment: I apologize I am trying to read the csv values into a Jagged Array. I will then execute a function based on each 'Type' from the Array and the values in the associated line

Answer (score 0):

`$_` is an "automatic variable" that represents the current item in the pipeline:

[about_Automatic_Variables | $_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.3#_)

> Same as $PSItem. Contains the current object in the pipeline object. You can use this variable in commands that perform an action on every object in a pipeline.

Note that `foreach( ... ) { ... }` is *not* a pipeline so `$_` does *not* contain a value - you probably want to reference the `$deviceImport` variable instead..

Also, it's not clear why you're doing `+=` rather than `=`. I'm guessing you want `=`.

To sum up, your code should probably be:

```
for( $i=0; $i -lt $deviceImport.Length; $i++ )
{
    $Devices[$i][0] = $deviceImport.id;
    $Devices[$i][1] = $deviceImport.name;
}
```

Finally, a bit of a nitpick, but your `$Devices` variable is not a [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) - it's a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) (basically a [single-dimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays) where each index itself contains another single-dimensional array).

Comment: Thank you. I am just being read into PowerShell for the first time and jagged array is not something I have encountered in other languages.

Comment: It's nothing magic, tbh - it's just an array that contains other arrays. Because each item is a separate array it can be a different length which would look "jagged" visually if you drew it - e.g. this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-or-array-of-arrays-in-c-with-examples/. Whereas a 2-dimensional array would be a nice tidy rectangluar grid.